# Python qestion about 2d arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matrix

Parameter should be the 2d array.The expected output is an index value of the 'peak' within the 2D array. The can be tested in main for example by running

```
 d = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]
  ]
print(find_peak_2d(d))
```

Comment: Please add input and expected output, some code will great to

Comment: Parameter should be the 2d array.The expected output is an index value of the 'peak' within the 2D array. The can be tested in main for example by running d = [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]
    ]
    print(find_peak_2d(d))

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can use a nested list comprehension with `max()`:

```
d = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6]]

def find_peak_2d(arr):
    result = max([max([(j, i, v) for i, v in enumerate(w)], key=lambda x:x[2]) for j, w in enumerate(arr)], key=lambda x:x[2])[:-1]
    return result

print(find_peak_2d(d))
```

Output:

```
(1, 2)
```

---

Let's break down this part:

```
max([max([(j, i, v) for i, v in enumerate(w)], key=lambda x:x[2]) for j, w in enumerate(arr)], key=lambda x:x[1])
```

First, lets have only:

```
max([max(r) for r in arr])
```

That will find the greatest number in the array, but not its index.
To find the greatest number's index, we need to use `enumerate` to iterate through the arrays, while keeping track of index:

```
max([max([(i, v) for i, v in enumerate(r)]) for r in arr])
```

As you can see, the inner list comprehension now keeps the index, value of each number.
But now we need to tell python *how* the `max` for that list should be determined, as we won't want python to simply find the `max` *index*!

For that, we can use a key, with a `lambda` function of `lambda x: x[1]`, so python will know to compare only the second index of each tuple to find the `max`.

```
max([max([(i, v) for i, v in enumerate(r)], key=lambda x:x[1]) for r in arr])
```

Now we have the index of the columns, time to find the index of the rows. It's basically the same thing, we use `enumerate`, and a key with a function of `lambda x: x[1]`:

```
max([max([(i, v) for i, v in enumerate(w)], key=lambda x:x[1]) for j, w in enumerate(arr)], key=lambda x:x[1])
```

Now, the index of the rows will get lost, as we didn't store it anywhere throughout the iterations. To fix that problem,
add the index here: `(i, v)` to `(j, i, v)`:

```
max([max([(j, i, v) for i, v in enumerate(w)], key=lambda x:x[1]) for j, w in enumerate(arr)], key=lambda x:x[1])
```

Which we will now need to change the the two `max`'s key to `lambda x:x[2]`, as the value of the tuple is now in the third index.
Finally, we omitting the value of the result using a slice of `[:-1]`:

```
max([max([(j, i, v) for i, v in enumerate(w)], key=lambda x:x[2]) for j, w in enumerate(arr)], key=lambda x:x[2])[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

By peak, I assume you mean largest value in each array?
This code return the index of the largest value in a 1D numpy array.
Just loop through each one and keep track of the value and index of the largest after each numpy array.
then simply return the index

```
result = numpy.where(d == numpy.amax(d))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [argmax](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) with [unravel_index](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html)

```
import numpy as np

def find_peak(d):
    # if list of lists convert to numpy.array
    if isinstance(d, list):
        d = np.array(d)
    
    ind = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(d, axis=None), d.shape)
    
    return ind
```

This would work for a N-dimensional array

```
d2 = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]
]
d3 = np.array([[0.40380192, 0.83570235, 0.55391089],
       [0.69123726, 0.22616673, 0.69294058],
       [0.20976952, 0.29562301, 0.26660186]])

print(find_peak(d2))
print(find_peak(d3))

# (1, 2)
# (0, 1)
```